# how to know width and height of merged cell in excel by using xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

I want to insert picture fully to merged cell by using xlwings.
so I want to know width and height of selected cell.

below is my code.

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
sht = wb.sheets.active
selected_sell = wb.selection
sht.pictures.add(image=Hardcopy_receive_filename, top=selected_sell.top, left=selected_sell.left, width=, height=,)
```

I want to input width of merged cell to widht=, height of merged cell to height=.

Comment: try to fit cell to image 
xw.Range('A1:B2').rows.autofit() like this 
https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html